# FileZilla always takes too long to start or do local operations

Tags: windows, ftp, sftp, filezilla, mapped-drive

I work with FileZilla Client during all the day, and I'm having a lot of problems when I need to do quick local actions (like create folders, for e.g.), and whenever I try to open it.

After clicking on the FZ icon, it may take 5 minutes to open. No matter how many times I've opened FZ on that day.

Just to clarify that, I use Windows 10 (64b) and I don't have any mapped network drivers. I've already checked both Online Providers and HKEY settings, there doesn't seem to be anything that would suggest that the PC is trying to connect or read any remote folders I may have forgotten.

Does anyone know any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm if there is any mapped drive by issuing a `net use` command from the Command Prompt or from the PowerShell.

FZ on its own only queries drive icons and drive labels, but there are many other potential causes for accesses to offline resources. For example:

- AV scanner scanning the entire network share just because the drive label was requested
- Mapped drive or UNC path in %PATH%
- Shell extension loaded from network resource
- The icon associated with a specific file type located on a network resource.

It could be even a disk failure. Scan your disk and check its S.M.A.R.T. status.